# how to solve the 'undefined method `network_traffic'' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, headless, capybara-webkit

I'm getting this error after recently switching from poltergeist to
webkit headless

> *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `network_traffic' for #Capybara::Selenium::Driver:0x007fc2f30bbbd0>

The offending line of code is

```
!page.driver.network_traffic.collect(&:response_parts).any?(&:empty?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you call `page.driver.xxxxxx` you're calling driver specific methods which may not be supported by any other driver.  `network_traffic` is one of those driver specific methods that is only supported by Poltergeist.  In the future, if you want your tests to be compatible across multiple drivers stay away from any `page.driver.xxxx` calls.

For this case, the code you show seems to be checking all responses had content.  I'm not sure how that fits into your specific test, but feature tests really shouldn't be worrying directly about specific network transfers, rather they should be worrying about the actual data displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Capybara driver should be [`Poltergeist`](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist), while you use `Selenium`.

`network-traffic` is not implemented for anything save for `Poltergeist`.

[More info](https://read.prettyco.de/inspect-network-traffic-in-capybara-with-poltergeist-16363ec8ecf4).

Comment: Oh really? And why is that?

Comment: Capybara driver DOESN'T NECESSARILY have to be Poltergeist, while you use Selenium.

Comment: If you want a `network-traffic`, that is implemented in `Poltergeist` driver only, the driver _must_ be `Poltergeist`, otherwise you’ll get the error you have got. Also stop using capslock for emphasis, it’s silly.